# Convert datetime string to with timezone in django based on active time zone

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-timezone

I am reading a get request and adding the data to db.

```
import dateutil.parser as dt

date_string = '2023-12-14 08:00:00'
date_obj = dt.parse(date_string)
```

It shows warning

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField RequestLab.end_time received a naive datetime (2023-12-14 08:00:00) while time zone support is active.

Is there any way i can convert this to date object with time zone

```
from django.utils import timezone

curr_timezone = timezone.get_current_timezone()
```

and store in the db..

I tried using various methods like

```
datetime_obj_test1 = date_obj.replace(tzinfo=curr_timezone)
datetime_obj_test2 = date_obj.astimezone(curr_timezone)
```

But these 2 are changing the time i.e for *timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"*

> datetime_obj_test1 = 2023-12-14 08:00:00+05:53

> datetime_obj_test2 = 2023-12-14 19:30:00+05:30

I am expecting this as output:

> 2023-12-14 08:00:00+05:30

Comment: Wait, your `datetime_obj_test1 ` is same with your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you received indicates that you're trying to store a naive datetime (one without an associated time zone) in a **DateTimeField** that expects aware datetimes (with a time zone).

Using make_aware is generally the recommended way to handle time zone conversions in Django.

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField RequestLab.end_time received a naive datetime (2023-12-14 08:00:00) while time zone support is active.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

To convert the naive datetime to a datetime with a specific time zone in Django, you have to use the **make_aware** function from **django.utils.timezone**.

Code:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import dateutil.parser as dt

date_string = '2023-12-14 08:00:00'
date_obj = dt.parse(date_string)

curr_timezone = timezone.get_timezone("Asia/Kolkata")

datetime_obj_with_timezone = timezone.make_aware(date_obj, curr_timezone)

print(datetime_obj_with_timezone)
```

Output:

```
2023-12-14 08:00:00+05:30
```

Comment: Thank you so much i was looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this

```
import pytz
import dateutil.parser as dt
from django.utils import timezone

date_string = '2023-12-14 08:00:00'
parsed_datetime = dt.parse(date_string)
curr_timezone = timezone.get_current_timezone()
aware_datetime = curr_timezone.localize(parsed_datetime)
desired_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
converted_datetime = aware_datetime.astimezone(desired_timezone)
print(converted_datetime)  # Output: 2023-12-14 08:00:00+05:30
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with time zones, it's crucial to be aware of the difference between naive and aware datetimes.

In your case, you want to convert a naive datetime to an aware datetime with a specific time zone. Here's how you can achieve this in Django:

`from django.utils import timezone
import dateutil.parser as dt

date_string = '2023-12-14 08:00:00'
date_obj = dt.parse(date_string)

// Assuming 'Asia/Kolkata' is the desired time zone
desired_timezone = timezone.pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

// Convert the naive datetime to an aware datetime with the desired time zone
aware_datetime = timezone.make_aware(date_obj, timezone=desired_timezone)

print(aware_datetime)`